# Creating TIN and contours in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, lidar, 3d-analyst, tin

I am upgrading from ArcView 3.1 to ArcMap 10.1. I have multiple LIDAR (bare earth) .txt files (x,y,z) that I would like to use to create a "TIN" (or is it Terrain Dataset in 10.1) and then contours?

I am unable to figure out how to do this in 10.1 and I have googled and read just about everything.

It was easy in ArcView 3.1 even though it had limitations (just a few steps). I have the full licensed 10.1 with all the 3D Analyst and variable extensions.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as I am currently working on a project?

Comment: For LiDAR you will need to use a terrain dataset which is designed to hold a very large amount of data. Once you've created a terrain dataset, convert XYZ files to points and load them into the dataset.

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to installing a fairly standard, free, standalone set of LiDAR tools, look into FUSION (software [here](http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/fusion/fusionlatest.html), manual [here](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fforsys.cfr.washington.edu%2Ffusion%2FFUSION_manual.pdf&ei=iquhVPDWGYLWoASEnIC4AQ&usg=AFQjCNEKbs__Reyz-ovCNRvTxtgyhqZzJA&bvm=bv.82001339,d.cGU)). XYZ2DTM tool will convert the .xyz to PLANS DTM format, then DTM2ASCII tool will convert the dtm to an ArcGIS-readable format. Then convert to TIN or contour as you choose.

edit: it looks like ArcGIS' [ASCII 3D To Feature Class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q900000041000000) (3D Analyst) may also give you the result you're after.

Comment: I can't say with any certainty. If it is a .txt file in .xyz format, I expect you can simply change the file extension to .xyz, but it will depend on the file.